# What actually norms store in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I came across a mapping where, on some fields, which uses `custom analyzer`, **norms** are disabled.

Then I read about Norms and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html found this official doc, but it doesn't explain clearly **what exactly it stores and how actually its useful in scoring**.

Below is the snippet from above link:

> Norms store various normalization factors that are later used at query
>   time in order to compute the score of a document relatively to a
>   query.

I found some other docs which gave some more information and advised to **Disable Norms for Analyzed Fields** like **numbers to represent the relative field length and the index time boost setting**. But still I am unable to understand it completely.

So, In short I have below doubts:

1. What exactly norms store?
2. What exactly is relative field length and how it's useful for scoring?
3. Default value of norms?
4. Can I see the content of norms using some ES query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is ma attempt of answer :)

*What exactly norms store and What exactly is relative field length and how it's useful for scoring?*

it stores information that allows elastic to know the relative field length. Why ?

> How long is the field? The shorter the field, the higher the weight.
>   If a term appears in a short field, such as a title field, it is more
>   likely that the content of that field is about the term than if the
>   same term appears in a much bigger body field

*Default value of norms?*

Norms are activated on text field and disabled on other fields.

*Can I see the content of norms using some ES query?*

No, norms are stored in the segment's data. But you can see the impact of the norms if you use the [explain flag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) in your request. Somewhere in the score explanation mess you will see some thing like that :

```
{
    "value": 1.4506965,
    "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
    "details": [
        {
            "value": 3,
            "description": "termFreq=3.0",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 1.2,
            "description": "parameter k1",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 0.75,
            "description": "parameter b",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 34.572754,
            "description": "avgFieldLength",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 48,
            "description": "fieldLength",
            "details": []
        }
    ]
}
```

where `fieldLength` and `avgFieldLength` are computed thanks to the `norms` data

This answer is primary based on https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm